# X250 trackpad multi finger gestures not working after Sleep

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

Im getting a issue that after resuming from sleep that the trackpad on my X250 doesn't seem to respond to any sort of multi touch and then I have to restart the machine to get it to work again. So the trackpad works.. but two finger scroll and drop/drop doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I have a *workaround*, hardly a solution. It's taken from the [debian wiki about Synaptics Touchpads](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Touchpad_does_not_work_after_resuming_from_hibernate.2Fsuspend). Unloading and reloading the `psmouse` kernel module fixes the problem for me:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Comment: Works for X280 as well.

Comment: Works for T480 as well.

Comment: works but it's better to use a permanent solution, cuz you'll need to run does commands whenever the problem occurs again

Comment: Hence the word "workaround". I would have loved to post a permanent solution, but I didn't have one. If can think of one, add it as an answer and I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 4):

[Here (in Post #44)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478) is another *workaround* mentioned (works great with my X240 and Ubuntu 18.10):

You need to edit your grub file (`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`) and change the following line
from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"` .

Then you need to update grub (`sudo update-grub`) and reboot your Computer.