# Touchpad is not scrolling on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad, thinkpad

On Ubuntu MATE 16.04, my touchpad scrolled just fine. Now, on Ubuntu 18.04 (gnome version, the basic one), it doesn't want to scroll when I go up and down at the right side of the touchpad like it used to scroll on 16.04 mate. Can someone help me what should I do to make it work? I have a Thinkpad T520 laptop.

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/a/1107157/153921

Answer (score 6):

## 1. Touchpad config via xinput

Check your **xinput** properties.

First you have to identify your touchpad, therefore type

```
xinput
```

which will output your devices. Search for something like touchpad,... and its identification number.

Now you can list the properties of your touchpad via following command (with the following hardware, the touchpad's id is 13):

```
xinput --list --long 13
xinput test 13 # now you can click, move, scroll and the terminal will output the input events from your touchpad
xinput list-props 13
```

Search for an entry something like **Vertical Scroll**.  You can set these properties via the **--set** commands. Look in the man page (`man xinput`) for a detailed description. So for instance if the **increment** is not set, you are not able to scroll.

## 2. Look in your Settings Gui

It is also possible that you have not set the touchpad correct in your config, therefore open the **Settings** program. Click on the left side on **Devices** and then on **Mouse & Touchpad**. For instance you should disable **Two-finger Scrolling** to get your wanted right scrolling. Also you have to enable **Edge Scrolling**!

Comment: This was very helpful i managed to solve my problem, thank you a lot !

Comment: @Cvele: If it solved your problem you can upvote and click on accepted answer! This will also other users having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had vertical scrolling on ubuntu LTS 16.04 but lost this when I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, the solution is:

```
Mouse & Touchpad > Disable: Two finger scroll
```

Vertical scrolling should return.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where do you input that?

Comment: @MattParrilla You go into the start menu, search `Mouse & Touchpad`, then go to the `Touchpad` tab, then find the `Scrolling method` dropdown

Answer (score 1):

I did the xinput method. I found out that my device is 14 and the property was 327 (edge scrolling).

By giving the command 'xinput set-prop 14 327 5 5 5' the edge scrolling works. I gambled on the '5'.

Answer (score 1):

You just need `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1` to be run in the terminal or else disable the Two Finger scrolling in your Device settings.

The above command works in almost all of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

I have thinkpad t549 and this worked for me: 
 $ sudo modprobe -r psmode
 $ sudo modprobe psmouse

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, on Ubuntu `18.04`, Mint (Cinnamon), T4xx series, I found that changing the `Mouse and Touchpad > Touchpad > General > Click actions` setting from `Automatic` to `Left click only` restored vertical scrolling capability.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you mouse is using Synaptics.

`synaptics | grep Scroll`

Make sure that VertEdgeScroll is 1. If not turn it on with
`synaptics VertEdgeScroll=1`

Same can be done for horizontal scroll with `synaptics HorizEdgeScroll=1`