# Touchpad scroll not working properly after Suspend

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I've recently done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10. I've experience an issue where the scroll function is not working properly after the system has been suspended. It's sluggish and slow, kinda like if it's only registering "half the scroll".

After a restart it works perfectly again. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I found a solution that restarts the touchpad automatically via a script. Posted how to as answer! :-)

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/a/1107157/153921

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After several tries, I managed to find a solution and made it run automatically after reading [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083719/run-a-command-as-su-after-every-wake-from-suspend). I've only tested it on Ubuntu 18.10:

Basically, restarting the touchpad with these commands fixes it:

First run:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

Then:

```
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

**But..** I didn't want to have to write those commands after every suspend. So I setup a script running the commands above automatically everytime I resume from suspend

**Run commands automatically after suspend:**

1) Create script with commands (open Terminal and type)

```
sudo touch yourscriptname.sh
```

This will create the file in your home folder.

2) Edit script

```
sudo nano yourscriptname.sh
```

Paste this in and save the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

modprobe -r psmouse && modprobe psmouse
```

3) Move to your "system" folder

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
```

4) Create service:

```
sudo touch yourservicename.service
```

5) Edit service:

```
nano yourservicename.service
```

Paste this in and save it afterwards

```
[Unit]
Description=Run user script after suspend
After=basic.target suspend.target hibernate.target

[Service]
User=root
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/home/yourusername/yourscriptname.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target suspend.target hibernate.target
```

6) Run chmod

```
sudo chmod +x /home/yourusername/yourscriptname.sh
```

7) Then run the following commands

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

And:

```
sudo systemctl enable yourservicename.service
```

**That should fix it!**

Comment: for a lenovo external keyboard+trackpoint, the reloaded module should be hid_lenovo instead of psmouse.

Answer (score 7):

Thinkpad Touchpad scrolling fixed (Permanently)!!!

First, go to the path and edit grub using any editor (run command using sudo).

Using vim editor:    `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

or

Using gedit editor:  `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Then, replace the existing line code in grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"
```

Then, save the file within the text editor.

Finally, update grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This instruction followed by a reboot worked for me (running 18.04 on T480)

Comment: Works for X240 on Linux Mint 20.

Comment: works for Thinkpad P50

Comment: Works for T480s with eOS Elementary OS 6 Odin (Ubuntu 20.04.3)

Answer (score 2):

just do the following

```
sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/psmouse-refresh
```

and paste these

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is the state (pre or post)-sleep
if [[ $1 == post ]]; then
    sudo modprobe -r usbhid
    sudo modprobe -r psmouse
    sudo modprobe psmouse
    sudo modprobe usbhid
fi
```

save and done

Comment: i think it should be made executable as well

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478/comments/63):

> Hi, please remove `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0` and comment out `blacklist i2c_i801` in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, and see if this helps.

That worked perfectly for my thinkpad