# Touchpad doesnt work until restart. Lenovo ideapad Yoga

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, 18.10

Well, at first it works perfect, but then it stopped. I can use a mouse, but my touchpad doesn't work. if I restart the computer then the touchpad works completely normal, but when I shutdown computer and turn on again the touchpad doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a couple of days ago where my touchpad wasn't working as it should after I suspended Ubuntu.

**Try running these commands in terminal:**

*(If your mouse isn't working just press ctrl+alt+T to open terminal)*

First:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

Second:

```
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

If that fixes it, you can write a script that starts whenever you "resume" the computer from being suspended. I write a [how-to in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124045/touchpad-scroll-not-working-properly-after-suspend)

**If the above isn't working:**

Since you are using a Lenovo laptop (like I am) there might be a chance that installing Synaptics would fix it (I just prefer libinput)

There is a great tutorial on how to do it [here](https://sangams.com.np/fix-ubuntu-18-4-touchpad-not-working-properly/)

Basically you need to run the following in Terminal:

```
xinput list
```

And check under "Virtual Core Pointer" and see if there is an input with "Synaptics" in it's name.

If there is run:

```
apt list --installed
```

And search for *xserver-xorg-input-synaptics*

If it's not installed, install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then reboot and hopefully that will fix your problems!