# Middle button & scroll do not work after suspend on a Thinkpad USB keyboard trackpoint

Tags: suspend, mouse, lenovo, thinkpad, trackpoint

I've recently acquired a thinkpad compact USB keyboard, that comes with a trackpoint.

When I suspend my Ubuntu 21.10 computer, the middle button of the trackpoint ceases to function until I unplug and replug the USB keyboard.

I've found several questions and answers on the site (mostly about what I suppose to be onboard trackpoints) suggesting that I should reload the psmouse module, though this does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you should reload is not psmouse, but hid_lenovo instead.

Thus, the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124045/touchpad-scroll-not-working-properly-after-suspend) works, but instead of reloading psmouse you should reload hid_lenovo instead.