# Touch-pad's two finger scrolling not working after sleep sometimes in Lenovo ThinkPad X1 carbon

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I have ThinkPad X1 carbon laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. Touchpad and gestures (Scrolling etc.) work perfectly. But sometimes after wakeup from sleep two-finger scrolling won't work. I have to restart the laptop to make it work again. Is there any workaround to prevent this?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/a/1107157/153921

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I could manage this using a temporary workaround by removing the touchpad module from the kernel and adding it again.
To remove:

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse`

To add again:

`sudo modprobe psmouse`

After that scrolling works for me.

Comment: aaahhh BIG THANKS.

Comment: Yup, that does the trick. Can confirm.

Comment: Can confirm, works for me too - what the hell is causing that though?